# How to click unopened tabs where the numbers change

Tags: python, selenium

How do I click all the unopened tabs pages where the value changes when you click tabs? (see image below)

Take the following [script](https://pastebin.com/e4yaEek0), based off of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46996782/not-clicking-all-tabs-and-not-looping-once-issues) with the following approach:

```
       clickMe = wait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, path + '[%s]' % str(index - 1))))
```

Works great for the large majority of pages, however I cannot see how it can be used in this case.  Any idea how you can get around this issue?

The reason it does not work is because as soon as you click an unopened tab, the number values change.  This means the job is trying to click elements that used to exist, but the number values changed when you opened a closed tab. This is better illustrated in the image below.

Say you had `//div[@class="KambiBC-collapsible-container KambiBC-mod-event-group-container"][1]` 
In the picture below, you can see that the above selector will change based upon when the job itself clicks tabs and upon loading the webpage.  The webpage has a habit of randomising opened and closed tabs.  So this explains why it will click some elements and then completely break or if you add try except, click only some elements and finish.

output:

```
1
2
3
4
#Stops working
```

Desired

```
1
2
3
4
etc,, (Clicks all the pages)
```

[image]
The above images are both:

```
//div[@class="KambiBC-collapsible-container KambiBC-mod-event-group-container"][1]`
```

You can see how this will cause issues later on.  The image on the right would not be able to locate //div[@class="KambiBC-collapsible-container KambiBC-mod-event-group-container"][11]  where a the one on the left could based on the order of tabs clicked.

[outerhtml](https://pastebin.com/zpNsxFFM)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using an index to reference these "tabs", you need an alternate way to uniquely identify each one.

One solution is to work with the developers of the site to get them to add an id or name attribute to the "KambiBC-collapsible-container" for each tab.

Another solution, if you're using the Page Object Model approach, would be to create a method on the page that provides a list of the available tabs that you can then reference by the header text.  Then you just keep track of which ones you've opened.

Yet another solution would depend on the functionality of the site.  You may be able to leverage the fact that if a tab has been opened it looks like the container has a class "KambiBC-expanded".  If a tab will stay open until you explicitly close it, you could simply get a list of all of the containers that do not have the "KambiBC-expanded" class and pick one to expand, repeating until there are no more to expand.